# How to retrieve data collection from cloud firestore database

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve all the fields in my collection, but i am only able to retrieve one field in the collection `personalinfo` instead of the entire content of the collection. Is there a way to retrieve all the fields in the collection of `personalinfo`?

this are my code to save data to cloud firestore database

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:grocery_shopping/pages/order_successful/order_successful.dart';

class PersonalInformation extends StatelessWidget {
   PersonalInformation ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  TextEditingController fullname = new TextEditingController();
   TextEditingController address = new TextEditingController();
   TextEditingController city = new TextEditingController();
   TextEditingController zipcode = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {



    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Checkout")),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: fullname,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Full Name"
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: address,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Address"
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: city,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "City"
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: zipcode,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Zipcode"
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                  Map <String,dynamic> data= {"field1": fullname.text,"field2": address.text,"field3": city.text, "field4": zipcode.text};
                  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("personalinfo").add(data);
                  } ,
                  child: Text("Submit"),
              ),


              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                 Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=> OrderSuccessful()));
                },

                child: Text("Continue"),
              ),

              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => Get.to(() => OrderSuccessful()),
                child: Text('Continue'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

this are my code for the data retrieve in cloud firestore database

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OrderSuccessful extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OrderSuccessfulState createState() => _OrderSuccessfulState();
}

  class _OrderSuccessfulState extends State<OrderSuccessful>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Order Successful")),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,

      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('personalinfo').snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
        if (!snapshot.hasData){
          return Text("no value");
        }
        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document){
            return Text(document['field1']);
          }).toList(),
        );
        },
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to access one field, then it means that you can access the remaining ones too.

If `document['field1']` works, then you can write `document['field2']` to get the second field & so on.

```
  class _OrderSuccessfulState extends State<OrderSuccessful>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Order Successful")),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,

      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('personalinfo').snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
        if (!snapshot.hasData){
          return Text("no value");
        }
        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document){
            // You can use a different widget like ListTile here if you want
            return Text(document['field1'] + " " + document['field2'] + " " + document['field3'] + " " + document['field4']);
          }).toList(),
        );
        },
        ),
    );
  }
}

// using ListTile widget
return ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(data['item1']),
      subtitle: Text(data['item2']),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: it worked. this is so helpful, thank you for your time answering this question! :D

Comment: how would I add ListTile to it? if you dont mind explaining, thank you.

Comment: I will update the answer with ListTile widget.

Comment: im not sure where to put the ListTile but thank you for answering 